# join doesn't make use of indexes

Tags: mysql

This query takes about 1s to run

```
select table2.name from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id and table1.value='PCF973F00'
```

while this one takes about 80ms

```
select table2.name from table2 where id = (select id from table1 where table1.value = 'PCF973F00')
```

`table1` has about 500K rows, `table2` has about 250K. `table1.id`, `table1.value`, and `table2.id` are all separate indexes. both `id` columns are uints, and `value` is a varchar 50.

The explains for the two queries are

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  table1  ref value,id    value   52  const   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  table2  ALL id  NULL    NULL    NULL    240858  Using where; Using join buffer
```

and
    id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra

```
1   PRIMARY table2  ref id  id  4   const   1   Using where
2   SUBQUERY    table1  ref value   value   52  NULL    1   Using where
```

table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `source_id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  KEY `value` (`value`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So my question is, why doesn't MySQL optimize the first query by using the index on `table1.value` and then joining via the indexes on both tables' `id` columns?

Comment: Your second query doesn't make sense.

Comment: Did you mean: `select table2.name from table2 where id IN (select id from table1 where table1.value = 'PCF973F00')`

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Comment: @Ray You're absolutely right it should be an `IN`, I think it happens to work as is just because the subquery only returns one row, in any case I get the same result with `IN`

Comment: @AndyLester I thought it was sufficient to include the number of rows in each table and the relevant indexed column types, which I did. The table is InnoDB, is there really anything else you need to know?

Comment: added table definitions to question